# Connecting to an external Database in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having a problem with connecting to a database in Xamarin, Android. This is what i have tried :

```
try
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=databases.000webhost.com;port=3306;database=id1817024_csftw;User Id=id1817024_csftw;Password=...;charset=utf8");

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
        txtSysLog.Text = "Successfully Connected";
    }
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{
    txtSysLog.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

The program doesn't seem connect to the database, neither on an emulator nor on my Nexus 5X. Watched lots of tutorials on YouTube, googled for the problems and still I couldn't make this work. Is this piece of code is the problem, or my setup on the database?

Comment: 1. Does it catch an error? If so what is the error?
2. What is the value of con.State before and after?

Comment: connecting directly to a remote database from a mobile client is almost always a horrible idea.  Use a webservice layer instead

Comment: Yes, it catches an error stating this : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts.

The value of con.State after the mysql connection line equals to ConnectionState.Closed

Comment: I'll look up webservice layers, haven't heard of it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect directly to a external database in xamarin, you need a layer between your app and database.That layer is called webservice.

I will help you do that.

1.Firstly create a database on 000webhost.com

2.Add a .php or .java file to connect and insert/select data from database in 000webhost file manager.

3.Access that .php file from your application with the help of httpclient class.

For example, if you have to insert name,email,phone number and password in database just call your .php file and pass your parameters as POST or GET.

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
                        string ss = "https://YOUR 000WEBHOST WEBSITE ADDRESS/database.php";
                        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Name", name.Text),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Email",email.Text),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Mobile", mobile.Text),
                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Password",password.Text)
                        });
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.PostAsync(ss, formContent);
                        var responsedone = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Actually, it is possible to connect to a external database from Xamarin; however, it is not a good programming practice because the database connection string will be included in the source code.

Comment: You can pass your credentials in the post request.
No need to put them into php code.

Comment: I've done everything like you said Yash. The program reaches the database.php file, which successfully connects to the database, however, I can't figure out how to direct the request to the database's table, to which I should insert the data in. 
By the way, could you help with the code which would extract data from the database to the xamarin program? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have uploaded my database.php file to Google Drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzasJ5B6P6zvVWIxNW5RYkRaeEk      I am having a table named 'user' and i have to insert name,email,phone number and password in it.I hosted it on 000webhost and my database is also on 000webhost so i have used localhost as server name.

Comment: There is no need to add your 000webhost database credentials in your .php file ,you can pass them in post request.

Comment: Yash, we can't make this work. With the code You wrote for xamarin + the code in php. The program runs fine, yet it doesn't change any of the values in the database. Does this work for you, if so, how so?

Comment: Yes ,it works for me.
The .php file I provided is for inserting data into database.

Comment: I can send you the whole code of ours, maybe you could look for what's wrong? We can't figure it out

Comment: Send me your email adress to which i'll send the code, please. Too long to copy paste it here